# node on heroku instance Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku

I'm trying to run an API served via heroku.  Currently I'm using SSL from let's encrypt, and i've added it to the site via the `domains and certificates` panel in the settings page. While I'm able to connect to the site on my browser with https, as well as postman I'm unable to use a node.js instance to access the API, getting the following error:

```
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
   at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1062:38)
   at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
   at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38) code: 
'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

I've tried using the `ssl-root-cas` module, but it doesn't seem to work on a heroku instance, as it needs to download intermeidate certificates and restart the server. However restarting the heroku instances causes the `ssl-root-cas` to simply lose the downloaded certificates.  I was also unable to serve the SSL certificate directly from my node server.  I need help fixing this issue, which I believe is a result of improperly bundling intermediate certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best, easiest way to fix this is simply use the `fullkey.pem` when heroku asks for a cert.